# How to use C# encode and decode 'Chinese' characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encoding, seo, urlencode

In my ASP.NET MVC application i am using Chinese Category Name, it was displayed as `%E8%82%B2%E5%84%BF` in IE's URL address, but the actual value is '育儿'.

I want to know how can I convert '育儿' into `%E8%82%B2%E5%84%BF` in C# and how can I convert it back, too. Is it possible display '育儿' in the URL link directly? Will it be good for SEO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The text displayed in IE's address bar is the URL encoded form of the hex version of those characters. The hex version of '育儿' encoded in UTF-8 is E882B2E584BF:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[] { 0xE8, 0x82, 0xB2, 0xE5, 0x84, 0xBF };
string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
```

s is equal to '育儿'.

You shouldn't transmit the straight chinese characters in the URL, it should be URL encoded using [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) and [UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

[HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx) will encode a URL, and [HttpUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx) will change it back.

Example:

```
string orig = "http://example.com/育儿";
string encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(orig);
// encoded should equal "http://example.com/%E8%82%B2%E5%84%BF"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to make sure that you are using the Unicode encoding (instead of the Default)?  Default encoding will not handle Chinese characters.

Comment: Can you kindly give me an example?