# How to allow chinese characters in url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-rewriting

I am redirecting my aspx page on

```
`http://www.ilanbio-international.com/News/4443/中国陕西西安---渭南验室奠基石庆典`
```

But pages gives an error that "page not found"

Are Chinese characters are allowed in URL?
If it is allowed then how can I redirect my page?
which Chinese characters are restricted in URL?

Comment: Think this might be what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375257/how-to-use-c-sharp-encode-and-decode-chinese-characters

Comment: Is that page supposed to be found on the internet right now ? because i can't find it, but i found: http://www.ilanbio-international.com/News/4444/Clootwijck-Group-participated-in-Potato-Workshop-in-China  wich is similar, but dosen't contain any chinese sign, maybe it can help you

Comment: Hi Antonie there is a Chinese flag in the right topmost corner it is used to translate the page into Chinese then you can go to the second last menu then click on Chinese heading then you will find the URL.

Comment: Have you solved it? I'm in the same situation!

Comment: yes I had solved the issue

Comment: please go to the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015257/allow-chinese-chracters-in-url-rewriting/34604551#34604551