# Allow chinese chracters in url rewriting

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I had wrote URL rewrite Rule:

```
<match URL="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-‘!@#$%^*()!~`\.&quot;]+)"/>
```

But there are some Chinese characters in my URL like:

```
'http://www.ilanbio-international.com/News/4443/中国陕西西安---渭南验室奠基石庆典'
```

Which is not support by this rule. 
So how can I support Chinese characters through URL rewriting?

Answer (score 2):

Just add this:

```
<match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-‘!@#$%^*()!~`\.&quot;\u4e00-\u9fa5]+)"/>
```

In place of this:

```
<match URL="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-‘!@#$%^*()!~."]+)"/>
```

Then your problem will solved.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the useful question and answer!
Just adding here for anybody has the same question but looking for an answer for the `Arabic Unicode characters (0600–06FF, 255 characters)` instead, then it is as follows:

```
<match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-\u0600-\u06FF]+)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for the unicode of the characters [here](http://www.ansell-uebersetzungen.com/gbuni.html) (if you are not using simplified chinese please search for `YourLanguage unicode table` on google.

if you want to write `丈` (this is the fifth character in the table i linked you to) you need to write `\u4E08` in which 4E08 is the unicode.
so `中国陕西西安` translates to `\u4E2D\u56FD\u9655\u897F\u897F\u5B89`.

.htaccess rules use RegEx for matching.

[regexr with example](http://regexr.com/3bum0)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a custom provider for URL rewrite and replace these Chinese characters with normal characters

refer http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module